# Get "undefined is not a function" when trying to use my collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using RequireJS to handle all of my dependencies.

So here's my View:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'bootstrap',
    'collections/InstitutionsCollection'
], function($, _, Backbone, InstitutionsCollection){

    var InstitutionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            var institutions = new InstitutionsCollection();

            institutions.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log("success!");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return InstitutionsView;
});
```

The error is thrown on this line:
`var institutions = new InstitutionsCollection();`

Here's my Collection:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/InstitutionModel'
], function($, _, Backbone, InstitutionModel){

    var InstitutionsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: InstitutionModel,
        url: '/institutions/'
    });

    return InstitutionsCollection;
});
```

And in case you need it, here's my Model:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone'
], function($, _, Backbone){

    var InstitutionModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    });

    return InstitutionModel;
});
```

I've stared at it for a while and I just can't figure out why it would be throwing that error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define your `view` you're importing bootstrap and mapping it to the `InstitutionsCollection` parameter in the require callback. Try updating your code as follows:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'collections/InstitutionsCollection',
    'bootstrap'
], function($, _, Backbone, InstitutionsCollection){

    var InstitutionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        render: function() {
            var institutions = new InstitutionsCollection();

            institutions.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    console.log("success!");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return InstitutionsView;
});
```

It can be a real pain keeping the mapping in sync and it's really easy to overlook when scanning the code!

Comment: Great, that was it! I knew it was going to be something small like that, I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As the others have suggested, you have the order of your parameters to the `define` callback incorrectly matched. I'd like to point out the sugar syntax which helps alleviate this common error:

```
define(function(require) {
    var $ = require('jquery');
    var _ = require('underscore');
    var Backbone = require('backbone');
    var InstitutionsCollection = require('collections/InstitutionsCollection');
    require('bootstrap');

    var InstitutionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
        // Code
    });

    return InstitutionsView
});
```

Read more about it [in the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar).

Answer (score 2):

You are mapping `bootstrap` to `InstitutionsCollection`. Change it to:

```
define([
  'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'collections/InstitutionsCollection',           
  'bootstrap'
], function($, _, Backbone, InstitutionsCollection){});
```